# bash tab completion only works for root

Tags: ubuntu, bash, bashrc, ubuntu-12.04, command-line-interface

I set up an Ubuntu 12 server (on rackspace cloud using their preconfigured image) and created a non-root user.  When I log in as the standard user, pressing [TAB] at the terminal outputs an actual tab and pressing [UP] outputs ^[[A .  If I log in as root however, [UP] enters my last command and [TAB] autocompletes.

The .bashrc files look exactly the same between the two users.  I really don't know where else to look.

Comment: Check /etc/passwd if that user has /bin/bash as shell and not something else.

Comment: you're right, it was set as /bin/sh.  why don't you post that as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per request posted as reply: Check /etc/passwd if that user has /bin/bash as shell and not something else.

Comment: i haven't used linux seriously in a number of years.  things have changed a lot.  i remember having to configure something to get my backspace working properly and so i just figured that this was probably similar.  thanks for your help!